# data type for character and numbers in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to store character and numbers for column have primary key in database.

I created the table through query in laravel like this

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //   $table->increments('id');
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->string('roll_no');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('father_name');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('cnic')->unique();
            $table->string('phone_no');
            $table->string('father_phone_no');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('dept_id');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary('roll_no');
            $table->foreign('dept_id')->references('dept_id')->on('departments')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

and set my column datatype string. which shows varchar in database looking fine. When i enter values in form the data stored perfectly like **12abc** but when i fetch data from database it shows only **12** without characters. 
And the function is

```
   public function showStudents()
    {
        $allStudents = Student::all();
//        $user = Auth::user();
        return view ('admin.students.showStudents', compact('allStudents'));
    }
```

and loop is

```
  @foreach($allStudents as $student)
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">{{ $student->roll_no }}</th>
                                    <td><a href="{{ action('AdminController@singleStudent', [$student->roll_no])}}">{{ $student->name }}</a></td>
                                    <td>{{ $student->address }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $student->phone_no }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $student->email }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $student->dept_id }}</td>
                                    <td><a href="{{ action('AdminController@editStudents', [$student->roll_no])}}" class="edit">Edit</a>  <a href="{{ action('AdminController@deleteStudent', [$student->roll_no])}}" class="delete">Delete</a> </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach``
```

What should i do to get proper and complete data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: for which column you have problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just paste this line to your model. So that modal can handle it without auto increment field.

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

On your model you should tell it that your primary_key isn't an autoincrement field.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'roll_no';
public $incrementing = false;
```

Should avoid the cast to integer.